# JavaScript scope exercise - cannot figure out why result is 10 (and not 30)

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm doing some scope exercises and came across the following question.

I honestly thought the answer was 30. I cannot figure out why `result` is equal to 10. To me, it seems like x would come from the global scope of 30.

I would appreciate any insight on this matter. Thanks so much.

```js
var x = 30;
    
function get () { return x; }
function set (value) { x = value; }

set(10);
var result = get(20);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What's the point of `20` in `get(20)`?

Comment: Nothing happens with the `20` being passed in `get()`. That function doesn't take an argument. All it does it return back to you the value of `x` at the time that you invoked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` does comes from the global scope, but before you call `var result = get(20);`, you call `set(10);` which assigns `10` to the global `x`.

Answer (score 1):

x does come from the global scope. `function set (value) { x = value; }` changes the value of x in the global scope.